# Где правильнее хранить абстракции?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Работаю с Symfony в связке с Doctrine.
Создавая сущности я часто использую абстрактные классы и трейты.
Где их хранить? В той же папке, что и сущности или вынести в отдельную папку (и в какую)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрим, какой подход использует Symfony, например, Symfony Serializer.

Используемый несколько раз в разных местах `Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareTrait` находится в корневой директории компонента. А, например, в директории 'Encoder' внутри этого компонента содержатся классы декодеров/энкодеров и одновременно, интерфейсы и абстрактные классы, используемые этими энкодерами/декодерами.

Таким образом, абстрактную конструкцию стоит расположить в пространстве имён, максимально близком к её реализациям.

Comment: Ага я также полистал классы Symfony и сделал такой же вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали какую версию symfony используете и используете ли вы бандлы

Если говорим о бандлах, то абстрактные классы для сущностей хранят в пространстве имён Entity, трейты по аналогии с интерфейсами хранить в пространстве имён Traits. Хотя и тут вы можете выбрать свою структуру.

Если говорить о том, что в symfony4 уходят от бандлов и форма проекта может быть сводобная, то делайте как вам удобно.

Если брать пример из компонентов не только симфони, но и вообще, то обычно хранят в корне компонента